# KeystoneJS: Relationships in Admin UI not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I am customizing KeystoneJS and I have run into an issue where it seems the relationship lists in my Admin UI have failed to update.

Specifically, I am looking at the default Post and Post Categories models with a relationship defined on the Post.categories field. If I add a category, it does not show up as an option for when creating or editing a Post.

Could there be some kind of data caching going on? Has anyone seen this issue, I am not seeing any errors and I can confirm the category has been created in MongoDB and the front-end can see and display the category just fine.

Thanks

Comment: This seems more like something you should raise as an [issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues) directly on the [Keystone repo](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues). Make sure you include some code to help us replicate the possible bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the v0.3 of Keystone. If you go to the following link

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/docs/guides/v0.3-to-v4.0-Upgrade-Guide.md#user-content-other-gotchas

It tells you that you need to update to v4.0.