# KeystoneJS: Error populating entries from database in version 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I recently ran into an issue with populating items using relationships in KeystoneJS 0.3.22. According to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613632/keystonejs-relationships-in-admin-ui-not-updating/42796553#42796553) this is an issue in version 3 but not in version 4.
After upgrading to version 4 I seem to be getting errors with my front end form that populates data from my database.

The error I am getting is:

```
    Sorry, an error occurred loading the page (500)

/home/dani/cns/templates/views/contact.pug:58
56| label Select the Clients that should be notified
57| select#selectboxgroups(name='groupSelect', multiple='multiple')
> 58| for record in records
59| option(value=record.groupname, selected=formData['record.groupname']) #{record.groupName}
60| .form-group
61| input(type='checkbox', name='smsmessage')

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The following code is my init function including the Group.model.find which is what populates the records.

```
view.on('init', function(next) {
        Enquiry.model.find().where('finalIncident', "No").select('incidentNumber updateNumber').exec(function(err,data){
            if(err)return console.log('error while fetching list of active incidents', err);
            var dataFiltered = getLatest(data);
            var incidents = [];
            for(var i=0; i<dataFiltered.length; i++){
                incidents.push({'incidentid': dataFiltered[i]._id, 'incidentNumber': dataFiltered[i].incidentNumber});
            }
            locals.incidents = incidents;
            //console.log(locals.incidents);
            return next();
        });
        Group.model.find().sort('name').exec(function(err,data){
            if(err)return console.log('error while fetching client list for contact page', err);
            var records = [];
            for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
                records.push({'groupid': data[x]._id, 'groupName': data[x].name });
            }
            locals.records = records;
            console.log(locals);
        });
    });
```

So far I have not been able to find any indications as to why this would be a problem. I have tried to change the variables used multiple times (I have seen an issue where using the wrong word and the plural of that word would cause problems) without any luck.

Does anyone have any ideas where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `next` prematurely; the view renders before you run your database query to get your `Groups`. You should either put the `Group.model.find()` call within your `Enquiry.model.find()` query, or use a control flow library like [`async`](https://npmjs.com/package/async) (which I think is installed with Keystone by default) to run both functions in parallel, set the locals, then render the view. Assuming you already have variables like `Enquiry`, `Group`, and `locals`...

```
var async = require('async');
view.on('init', function(next) {
    async.parallel([
        function (cb) {
            Enquiry.model.find().where('finalIncident', "No").select('incidentNumber updateNumber').exec(function(err,data){
                if(err) return cb('error while fetching list of active incidents', err);
                var dataFiltered = getLatest(data);
                var incidents = [];
                for(var i=0; i<dataFiltered.length; i++){
                    incidents.push({'incidentid': dataFiltered[i]._id, 'incidentNumber': dataFiltered[i].incidentNumber});
                }
                locals.incidents = incidents;
                //console.log(locals.incidents);
                return cb(null);
            });
        },
        function (cb) {
            Group.model.find().sort('name').exec(function(err,data){
                if(err)return cb('error while fetching client list for contact page', err);
                var records = [];
                for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
                    records.push({'groupid': data[x]._id, 'groupName': data[x].name });
                }
                locals.records = records;
                console.log(locals);
                return cb(null);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, results) {
        console.log(err);
        return next();
    });
});
```

Comment: I already had those set in another find function. Let me edit my original post with my entire init code. Also the var locals and the view.render are also part of the file already. I did not want to post the entire file as it has quite a bit of other stuff.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I made the necessary modifications for the async but still can't seem to get the data to populate. When I log the locals variable I see all the data in my terminal screen but am still unable to populate it on the front end.

Comment: So `-console.log(locals);` returns nothing in your Pug/Jade template? Add `console.log(locals)` in the last callback function; does either return anything?

Comment: So console.log within the callback function works and shows me the correct data. When putting console.log within the pug template  I get a blank data.      records:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],

Comment: I believe I found the problem.... The data is there but the dropdown isn't rendering properly... Sorry about that. Fixing it now but should be all good.